# 4 images per row using masonary and css

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying my best to do 4 images in a row. I have change widths but it isn't happening. Here is kind of look i want.
[image]

I am using masonry too. Here is live link [Link](http://csdm4.com/develop/)

Comment: At the moment it's fixed width articles in a responsive container. So on my screen I see 5 in a row. You need to make the individual items a percentage width of their parent

Comment: @ilovecode 5 in a row thats strange for me. I am on 1366x768 and on ubuntu chrome and i only see 3. Thank you.